# How to use two colours (wave gradient) as background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a background like this picture.

[image: background]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

my approach was by CustomPainter :

this Code :

```
class WaveBackground extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color firstColor;
  final Color secondColor;
  final Widget? child;
  const WaveBackground(
      {Key? key,
      required this.firstColor,
      required this.secondColor,
      this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: firstColor,
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            painter: _WaveCustomPaint(backgroundColor: secondColor),
            size: Size.infinite,
          ),
          child ?? Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _WaveCustomPaint extends CustomPainter {
  Color backgroundColor;
  _WaveCustomPaint({required this.backgroundColor});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var painter = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    var path = Path();
    var height = size.height;
    var width = size.width;

    path.moveTo(0, height / 3 + height / 5);
    var des1 = width / 4;
    var des2 = height / 3 + height / 10; //height/5 /2
    path.quadraticBezierTo(des1, des2, width / 2, height / 3 + height / 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        width / 2 + width / 4, height / 3 + height / 10, width, height / 3);
    path.lineTo(width, height);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.lineTo(0, height / 3 + height / 5);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can make stack as your Root Widget, Now in the children put a container with background Color as your first child in stack.

The second child should be Container with clipPath Widget, you can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) to make it easier to get the shape you want

**The code :**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      //! backgroun
      Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      //! clipPath
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: WaveClipperTwo(reverse: true),
          child: Container(
            height: 320,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
     // reset of your code
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it using `Stack` and `Column` with `Row`.

**Code:**

```dart
{
body: Stack(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(205),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(205),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(205),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(205),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
}
```

Result Image

[image: Result Image]